# MVC: Button not firing click event in a tablecell

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

EDIT - I am putting in more info to help get the answer.
What I am doing is using autocomplete to add items to a list;

```
   <section id="rightSide" class="shrinkwrap" style="float: right;margin-top:10px;width:500px;">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select Other Materials</legend>
            <form method="get" action="@Url.Action("CreateOtherMaterials", "DataService")"
                  data-scd-ajax="true" data-scd-target="#otherMaterialList">
                <p>Select a Material: <input type="search" name="searchOtherMaterial" id="searchOtherMaterial" data-scd-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutocompleteOtherMaterial", "DataService")" style = "width: 300px;" class="submitOtherMaterialSelectionNew" data-scd-add-other-material="@Url.Action("AddOtherMaterialNew", "DataService")"/>
                    @Html.DialogFormButton("Add New Material", Url.Action("AddMaterial", "Popup"), "Add New Material", null, Url.Action("Create"))
                </p>
            </form>  

            @Html.Partial("_OtherMaterials", Model.SupplierMaterialList.Where(x => x.PrimaryMaterialFlag == false).ToList())

        </fieldset>
    </section>
```

So everytime an item is entered, the list grows. I am wondering if the problem is that the script does not pick up the latest updates to the page?
The partial view _OtherMaterials looks like

```
@model IList<SupplierMaterial>

<div id="otherMaterialList" >
    <p>These materials have now been added for this supplier</p>
    <table>
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </table>
</div>
```

This is a grid that uses the DisplayTemplate below to display rows of data;

```
@model SupplierMaterial
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Material.MaterialName </td>
    <td>
        <form class="shrinkwrap" method="get" action="@Url.Action("RemoveOtherMaterial", "DataService")">
            <input type="button" value="Remove" class="removeItem"/>
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MaterialId)
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

The form does not overlap with any other.
When the user clicks on the button this code is meant to run;

```
$('.removeItem').click(function () {
    alert("test");
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $tr = $(this).closest("tr");
        $tr.remove();
    });

    return false;
});
```

However the click event is not captured by this code, and I can't work out why

Comment: Are you getting that `alert()`?

Comment: what is your purpose to include `return false` at the end..?

Comment: Can you post your HTML please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are working with dynamic content that has been added to the page on the fly, event handlers like `click()` will not get bound to dynamically added selectors by itself.

you should put your code in `delegate()` or `on()` indside document load that can handle future contents.

```
$('body').delegate('.removeItem', 'click', function(){
var $form = $(".shrinkwrap");
var options = {
    url: $form.attr("action"),
    type: $form.attr("method"),
    data: $form.serialize()
};

$.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
    var $tr = $(this).parent("tr");
    $tr.remove();
 });
});
```

you can use much more closer selector than `body` to make the response more faster. you could also use `live('selector', function(){});` but it has been deprecated as of `jQuery v1.9`. Hope this helps.

Comment: I think live has been replace with on?

Comment: The delegate does the job. Now I know when to use it.

Comment: glad that worked for you, `on()` was not replaced with `live()` it was added in when `live()` and `delegate()` was in existance as an alternative but much expressive. but `live()` was dropped from set of jQuery API from `jQuery v1.9`. however it will work till `v1.8.3`

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
alert(test);
```

with

```
alert('test');
```

I think here you have stuck up and try like this

```
$('.removeItem').click(function () {
    var $form = $(".shrinkwrap");
    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $tr = $(this).parent("tr");
        $tr.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Good point, although I put that there when it was not working

Comment: Because it is a display template and repeated many times, the var $form will be a collection of forms which is not what I want. I appreciate advice on how I can improve the code. The main issue is that the event is not firing and the alert is not running