# $(this).parent("tr").remove(); doe not delete the tablerow from the view

Tags: jquery

This is a question that follows on from my previous question; [MVC: Button not firing click event in a tablecell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670608/mvc-button-not-firing-click-event-in-a-tablecell?noredirect=1#comment23985513_16670608)

Because I am creating a grid dynamically, I have to use a jquery delegate in order to attach an event to a button in the grid.

So I have this section in my view;

```
   <section id="rightSide" class="shrinkwrap" style="float: right;margin-top:10px;width:500px;">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Select Other Materials</legend>
            <form method="get" action="@Url.Action("CreateOtherMaterials", "DataService")"
                  data-scd-ajax="true" data-scd-target="#otherMaterialList">
                <p>Select a Material: <input type="search" name="searchOtherMaterial" id="searchOtherMaterial" data-scd-autocomplete="@Url.Action("AutocompleteOtherMaterial", "DataService")" style = "width: 300px;" class="submitOtherMaterialSelectionNew" data-scd-add-other-material="@Url.Action("AddOtherMaterialNew", "DataService")"/>
                    @Html.DialogFormButton("Add New Material", Url.Action("AddMaterial", "Popup"), "Add New Material", null, Url.Action("Create"))
                </p>
            </form>  

            @Html.Partial("_OtherMaterials", Model.SupplierMaterialList.Where(x => x.PrimaryMaterialFlag == false).ToList())

        </fieldset>
    </section>
```

The Partial View _OtherMaterials looks like

```
@model IList<SupplierMaterial>

<div id="otherMaterialList" >
    <p>These materials have now been added for this supplier</p>
    <table id="tableOtherSupplierList">
        @Html.DisplayForModel()
    </table>
</div>
```

And my display template;

```
@model SupplierMaterial
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Material.MaterialName </td>
    <td>
        <form class="shrinkwrap" method="get" action="@Url.Action("RemoveOtherMaterial", "DataService", new { id = Model.MaterialId })">
            <input type="button" id="btnRemove" value="Remove" class="removeItem"/>
        </form>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I use this query remove a row in the grid when the Remove button is clicked;

```
 $('body').delegate('.removeItem', 'click', function () {
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method")
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        $(this).parent("tr").remove();
    });

    return false;
});
```

I tried replacing the body element with something closer such as #tableOtherSupplierList but that did not work. I would like to use on() instead of delegate but so far only the above code seems to work.
The main issue I have however is that the line $(this).parent("tr").remove(); does not modify my view and remove the tablerow.
How do I fix this?

Comment: $(this) inside done() most likely doesn't refer to any dom element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you want:

```
var removeItemEl = $(this);
$.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
    removeItemEl.closest("tr").remove();
});
```

`parent` only travels up 1 level. And since .removeItem is within the form, you need `closest`.

And like foxx was saying, by using `this` inside the done callback, you're not targetting the dom element. So you have to assign it as a local variable (`var removeItemEl = $(this);`).

Comment: That is the correct answer. I will tick you when the time restriction allows me. Would you use delegate or would you use on? Would you use body as the selector? I find that only body seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

`$(this)` inside your `done()` function didn't refer to the original dom element anymore..

```
$('body').delegate('.removeItem', 'click', function () {
    var element = $(this);

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        element.parent("tr").remove();
    });

});
```

If it still doesn't work, then `tr` is not the parent of .removeItems, just do some console.logging to see if the `element.parent("tr")` is matching the element you want to remove.

You might want to check this as well [Difference between jQuery parent(), parents() and closest() functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9193212/difference-between-jquery-parent-and-closest-function)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
$('body').delegate('.removeItem', 'click', function () {
    var $form = $(this).closest("form");
    var $elem = $(this);
    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method")
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        $elem.closest("tr").remove();
    });

    return false;
});
```